# Shadows built-in names "function" and "module" with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following Python code:

```
function = "Developer"
module = "something"
print(function + " on " + module)
```

With PyCharm 2017, I have a bubble which says “Shadows built-in names "function"/"module" with PyCharm”.

I’m surprised because "function" and "module" are not built-in names. They are not keywords either:

```
import __builtin__
import keyword

assert "function" not in dir(__builtin__)  # -> OK
assert "module" not in dir(__builtin__)    # -> OK
assert "function" not in keyword.kwlist    # -> OK
assert "module" not in keyword.kwlist      # -> OK
```

What’s wrong?

I’m using CPython 2.7, but have the same trouble with 3.5 & 3.6.

**EDIT:**

`__builtin__` is now `builtins` in Python 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`function` is "defined" in `builtins.pyi`:

```
class function:
    # TODO not defined in builtins!   
    __name__ = ...  # type: str
    __qualname__ = ...  # type: str
    __module__ = ...  # type: str
    __code__ = ...  # type: Any
    __annotations__ = ...  # type: Dict[str, Any]
```

Keep in mind I used "defined" vs defined. Check out this absurdity:

```
foo = function
```

raises

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 117, in <module>
    foo = function
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

Yet if you do `function = 'a'` the IDE will complain (as you noticed) that this shadows a built-in name (even though `function` is clearly not *actually* defined).

The exact behavior repeats with `module`.

This is because (as far as I understand, anyone please correct me if I'm wrong) `pyi` files are only there to provide type hints (as [PEP-484 suggests](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files)).

So, I'm not sure if this warning is a bug in Pycharm's linter (perhaps it should not be looking at "definitions" in `.pyi` files) or an intended behavior.

Either way, *module* and *function* are probably not good variable names anyway.

Comment: I still don't understand why "function" exist in PyCharm stubs…

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE That you'll need to ask JetBrains, but like I explained in my answer, it is most probably to somehow assist with type hinting.

Comment: I found the [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/) reference on GitHub. Quote: “Each Python module is represented by a `.pyi` "stub". This is a normal Python file (i.e., it can be interpreted by Python 3), except all the methods are empty. Python function annotations ([PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)) are used to describe the types the function has.”

Comment: Currently, the best answer I had: This is a historic artefact. Probably it will be removed at some point, the problem is that will require lots of tiny tedious changes in [mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/) code.

Answer (score 2):

Per [PY-8672](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8672), since March 2014 there is an ability to ignore certain names with this inspection. Open Settings, search "Shadowing built-ins", click on the inspection name, and use the Options section to add names the inspection should whitelist.