# "Unwraping" and wrapping again @staticmethod in meta class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I want to create metaclass which will decorate every function with trace decorator.

So I got this:

```
from functools import wraps
from inspect import getfile

from arrow import now


def trace(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(
            '{timestamp} - {file} - {function} - CALL *{args} **    {kwargs}'.format(timestamp=now().isoformat(sep=' '),
                                                                                                 file=getfile(f),
                                                                                 function=f.__name__, args=args[1:],
                                                                                 kwargs=kwargs))
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(
            '{timestamp} - {file} - {function} - RESULT     {result}'.format(timestamp=now().isoformat(sep=' '),
                                                                         file=getfile(f),
                                                                         function=f.__name__,
                                                                         result=result))
        return result

    return wrapper


class TraceLogger(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        for attr in dct:
            value = dct[attr]
            if callable(value):
                dct[attr] = trace(value)
        return super(TraceLogger, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)


class ExampleClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = TraceLogger

    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        print('bar')

example = ExampleClass()
example.foo()
example.bar()
```

Tracing works for any non static functions because staticmethods are not callable.
How can I unwrap staticmethod then wrap it two times in **new** metclass like this:

```
dct[attr] = staticmethod(trace(value))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `staticmethods are not callable`? They are, otherwise you wouldn't be able to call them

Comment: Hi @DeepSpace staticmethod objects don't meet this condition
                if callable(value):
                    dct[attr] = trace(value)

Comment: I understand. Your question boils down to "Why `callable(ExampleClass.bar)` returns `True` while `callable(ExampleClass.__dict__['bar'])` returns `False`" which is a very interesting question. Perhaps you want to simplify your question a bit as this is not related to the metaclass.

Comment: `staticmethod` objects are descriptors, and when accessing them, Python returns a callable function. They themselves are indeed not callable.

Answer (score 2):

You can unwrap a `staticmethod` object by calling `__get__` on it.

```py
@staticmethod
def func(*args):
    print('func called:', args)
    return 42

print(func)
print(func.__get__(None, object))
print(func.__get__(None, object)(1, 2, 3))
```

It outputs:

```
<staticmethod object at 0x7f8d42835ac0>
<function func at 0x7f8d429561f0>
func called: (1, 2, 3)
42
```

As for why this works, you may be interested in learning about what the descriptor protocol is, and I recommend [this link](https://realpython.com/python-descriptors/).

Answer (score 1):

(I linked to three different questions/answers in this answer because I wanted to provide as much details as possible rather than just close as duplicate. If you upvote this answer please consider to upvote the linked answers as well)

You have stumbled upon an interesting 'feature' of Python which is explained in the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243293/do-static-method-object-and-class-method-object-not-have-callable-types) question.

Instead of `if callable(value)` you could have checked `if isinstance(value, (function, staticmethod, classmethod))` but this would only lead to another interesting corner-case: `NameError: name 'function' is not defined` (see why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214672/shadows-built-in-names-function-and-module-with-pycharm/45214849#45214849)) (Even doing `import builtins ; ... ; builtins.function` will lead to an error).

You can't get away from the need to check if an attribute name is a method, staticmethod or a classmethod, and the (arguably, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624939/1453822) why) correct way in your case to do it is to use `types.FunctionType`:

```
import types

...

if type(value) == types.FunctionType: # or isinstance(value, types.FunctionType)
    dct[attr] = trace(value)

...
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.