# Is it possible to unwrap classmethod in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class-method

I want to unwrap a classmethod into an instance method. Is it possible to do it?

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def my_classmethod(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        ...


class B:
    # in this case my_uwrapped_method is still a classmethod
    my_uwrapped_method = A.my_classmethod
```

Is it possible to unwrap the my_classmethod into a instance method with some python magic, meanwhile retaining the same code from the original method?

I found this way of unwrapping a staticmethod here:
["Unwraping" and wrapping again @staticmethod in meta class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694087/unwraping-and-wrapping-again-staticmethod-in-meta-class)

But the same does not work with classmethods, unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe it's better to have separated method which you would call in your  my_classmethod? And if you didn't want to use classmethod you could call that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 ways to unwrap a `classmethod`:

```py
A.my_classmethod.__func__  # Get the bound method

A.__dict__['my_classmethod'].__wrapped__  # Unwrap the `classmethod` object
```

After unwrapping the classmethod, it can be wrapped again to be applied to a new object.

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def my_classmethod(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        ...


class B:
    # New classmethod bound to `B`
    my_classmethod2 = classmethod(A.my_classmethod.__func__)
```